# Why does this Union Range in VBA select unwanted cells in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, foreach, basic

I'm trying to make my life a bit easier and fill in some values in some cells by using a macro that is activated by a button, the macro looks like this:

```
Sub Fill_123()

Dim unionRange As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets(1)

With ws
    Set unionRange = Union(.Range("G48:G48"), .Range("G51:G51"), .Range("G55:G55"), .Range("G58:G58"), .Range("G60:G60"), .Range("G61:G61", .Range("G63:G63")))
End With

Dim myCell As Range

For Each myCell In unionRange
    If myCell.Address = "$G$60" Then
        myCell = myCell + 1
    ElseIf myCell.Address = "$G$63" Then
        myCell = myCell + 3
    Else
        myCell = myCell + 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

This macro will fill in the following cells:

[image]

If you look close enough you can see I did not select G62 but somehow it is adding a "1" to this cell, how is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You didn't close the parenthesis after `Range("G61:G61"`, which caused it create a contiguous range from G61:G63.

Comment: @basodre good spot :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Union` you could also use `Set unionRange = .Range("G48,G51,G55,G58,G60,G61,G63")` which would be the same just shorter.

Also you could replace your `If … End If` with

```
If myCell.Address = "$G$63" Then
    myCell = myCell + 3
Else
    myCell = myCell + 1
End If
```

which is shorter but exactly the same.

Comment: I can't be 100% sure, but gut-feeling says a comma-separated string of range addresses at one point or another turns into `Union` method calls, i.e. "would be the same just shorter". Explicit `Union` is useful for things like conditionally deleting rows without iterating backwards and/or causing a recalc every time, that is, *when you don't know at compile-time what cells you're going to be working with*. Using `Union` with hard-coded addresses is therefore more complicated than it needs to be. +1 for a simpler solution involving fewer parantheses to keep track of!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Yes, good thoughts. And worth to mention that there is a 255 character limit for range addresses. So in this particular case with only 7 addresses this works. If there is more than 255 chars to be used you would need to switch to use `Union`.